# Restricting dynamically loaded classes and jars based on a security policy

Tags: java, security

I would like to dynamically load a set of jars or classes (i.e. plugins loaded at runtime).  At the same time, I would like to restrict what these plugins are able to do in the JVM.  For a test case, I would like to restrict them to pretty much everything (right now I'm just allowing one System.getProperty value to be read).

I am currently using a security policy file, but I'm having difficulty specifying a policy for one folder or package in my codeBase, but not another.

Here is how my policy looks now:

```
grant codeBase "file:/home/max/programming/java/plugin/plugins/" {
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.version", "read";
};
grant codeBase "file:/home/max/programming/java/plugin/api/" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Where (for testing purposes), all files in the plugins package and folder are restricted, but the classes in the api folder are not.  Is this possible?  Do I have to create a custom class loader?  Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you have in those folders? .class files or .jar files? In order for Java to consider .jar files your codebases should end with /* or /- (for reference, see: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/policyfile.html)

Comment: If you really don't trust the plugin code, then you should load it in a different class loader (this is something that has apparently been forgotten, but known in the relatively early days of the Java2 security model...).

Comment: The answer on this page has been very helpful to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502218/sandbox-against-malicious-code-in-a-java-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer solved my problems:
[Sandbox against malicious code in a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502218/sandbox-against-malicious-code-in-a-java-application)