# Custom Class loader to restrict access to classes

Tags: java

My application have this custom classloader:

```
JarByteClassloader loader = new JarByteClassloader(jar);
Class c = loader.loadClass(classToLoad);
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
JarEntryObject jarEntry = (JarEntryObject) c.newInstance();
```

I'd like to ask if it's possible to restrict access to specific classes from the instances loaded by a custom classloader?

As such, for example, `System.getProperty()` or `System.getenv()` should fail. In what way can this be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626981/restricting-dynamically-loaded-classes-and-jars-based-on-a-security-policy This might be helpful to you.

Comment: Looks like you have to set SecurityManager  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html

Answer (score 2):

While for this exact situation, a SecurityManager might be the best fit (even though it is deprecated and marked for removal without replacement since Java 17), you actually can restrict access to other classes via the class loader.

This can be done by overriding your class loader's `loadClass` method.
It is essential to understand the delegation model for class loaders to restrict it:

> The ClassLoader class uses a delegation model to search for classes
> and resources. Each instance of ClassLoader has an associated parent
> class loader. When requested to find a class or resource, a
> ClassLoader instance will delegate the search for the class or
> resource to its parent class loader before attempting to find the
> class or resource itself. The virtual machine's built-in class loader,
> called the "bootstrap class loader", does not itself have a parent but
> may serve as the parent of a ClassLoader instance.

The role of the `loadClass` method is the following:

> Loads the class with the specified binary name. The default
> implementation of this method searches for classes in the following
> order:
>
> - Invoke findLoadedClass(String) to check if the class has
>   already been loaded.
> - Invoke the loadClass method on the parent class loader. If the parent
>   is null the class loader built-in to the virtual machine is used,
>   instead.
> - Invoke the findClass(String) method to find the class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

So if we override `findClass` our code is only called if the parent class loader could not load/find the class. But we want to intercept all loaded classes, so we need to override `loadClass` instead:

```
@Override
public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    synchronized (getClassLoadingLock(name)) {
        if (allowDelegateLoadingOf(name)) {
            System.out.println("Delegate loading of " + name + " to parent class loader.");
            return super.loadClass(name);
        }

        System.out.println("Prohibit class from delegating: " + name);
        return findClass(name);
    }
}
```

In this case the `allowDelegateLoadingOf` is just a simple boolean method that determines if a class should be delegated and therefore loaded or not. This can be done by simply checking the class name against a list of whitelisted or blacklisted packages/classes.