# In java what are the packages containing operating system level commands?

Tags: java, operating-system, java-io

I want to to detect whether a given program can perform malicious operations like forking , interprocess piping , input/output redirection, file handling etc.
Actually I am developing a program that checks java codes and do not want the coder to harm my code checker system in any way.
What are the packages I should look for in code to ensure this ?
Thanks in advance... !

Answer (score 1):

Would your checks be at compile time or at runtime?

- If you check at runtime, you could use a security manager with permissions. Have a look at [Security Manager Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html). There is a wide list of permissions. You can disallow file access, even open frames.
- As for base classes, you would have to be careful with `java.lang.Runtime` and `java.lang.System`, `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`. These create `java.lang.Process`. Also `java.io.File`, `java.io.FileDescriptor`, maybe even Sockets and `java.nio.*` operate on the OS/file system.
- I would also disallow reflection, `java.lang.reflect.*`, and some methods of `java.lang.Class` are reflective too. Loading classes by name might workaround your checks. Some classes in `java.beans.*` are using reflection as well.
- Depending on your needs, you might even want the user code to run in a [sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502218/sandbox-against-malicious-code-in-a-java-application). But that might go too far for you. Checking for class usage (constant pool) might be an easy way.
- As Colin HEBERT pointed out before, `native` is also dangerous. But some of them are definitely needed, like `Object`'s methods.

Comment: +1 for mentioning reflection. You can use reflection to call the methods you've mentioned in other classes. And there are other classes, such as in `java.beans`, that allow relatively free use of reflection indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the OS-interaction functionality is provided in `java.lang.Runtime` and `java.lang.System`.  Note that these wouldn't require imports, because they're in the `java.lang` package.

But... if you're just analyzing the code, why would you care what calls it contains?  Perhaps you should be looking at [Java Security](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/spec/security-specTOC.fm.html) instead of which classes get called.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about checking also all methods marked as "native".

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: java.lang. I believe that's the only "out of the box" package that includes classes that give you access to OS functions. Well, I'm assuming here that you don't include I/O as "OS-related" stuff. If you do, then you'd also have to include the java.io, javax.swing, and a couple of other packages.

Longer answer: A programmer could write his own JNI functions that interact with the OS and put them in any package he likes. Trying to identify this could be quite tricky. Well, I guess you could say that any "native" function is automatically suspect.