# Java Thread Level Sandbox

Tags: java, multithreading, security, sandbox

Is it possible to sandbox against untrusted code at thread Level ?

The common answer to [sanboxing code seem to be implementing a SecurityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502218/sandbox-against-malicious-code-in-a-java-application) and replacing the default SecurityManager. But this imposes the sandbox at the JVM Level .
This is unsuitable for me.

Is there a way to do it for particular threads only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it. Since threads share a lot of resources (address space etc), it is hard to envisage a practical mechanism for doing what you're asking. Your best bet might be to run the untrusted code in a separate process.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is to start a new JVM process , get data objects from the JVM running the Trusted code , Execute the untrusted code and return the result to the Trusted JVM ?

Comment: Yes, something along those lines.