# How to sandbox a Java program

Tags: java, php, multithreading, ide, classloader

I have been trying to build an online java compiler. And I have looked some answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502218/sandbox-against-malicious-code-in-a-java-application). But there are still something I don't understand.

1. I use `java -Djava.security.manager HelloWorld.class` in PHP to run users' Java code now. But as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502218/sandbox-against-malicious-code-in-a-java-application) said, I need to `Run the untrusted code in its own thread`. Do I really need to build thread? If I don't, what will it cause? (All of users code are stored in different documents, but class name may be the same)
2. If I successfully implement thread and classloader, should I put these two classes in different files? Say, thread in one file, classloader in another?
3. If I use the way [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502218/sandbox-against-malicious-code-in-a-java-application) says (which is thread + classloader + securitymanager), does that mean I cannot compile code in command line? And instead of it, I should run the Java file which includes `thread + classloader + securitymanager` and pass some variables to this class?

Sorry, please bear my question. I know a little Java, there are too many simple things I need to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java -Djava.security.manager -java.security.policy=filename.policy HelloWorld.class
```

Where filename.policy is a file on the harddrive with no entries at all will "sufficiently" sandbox the code and prevent it from doing malicious writes/read on your PC.

The problem with just running that alone is that infinite loops are allowed and it would possibly consume all your CPU power and never stop.

The fix for that is indeed to create a new different program, which creates a new Process that it launches and only allows that Process to exist for a certain timeframe before terminating it (violently).

Here's some code I made for this (butchered from old code):

```
class TestProcess {
    private static final ExecutorService THREAD_POOL = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        List<String> out = new ArrayList<>();
        IntegerCallable ic = new TestProcess.IntegerCallable(out);
        int returnVal = timedCall(ic);
    }

    private static <T> T timedCall(Callable<T> c) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        FutureTask<T> task = new FutureTask<>(c);
        THREAD_POOL.execute(task);
        return task.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


    public static class IntegerCallable implements Callable<Integer> {
        private final List<String> output;
        private Process process;

        public IntegerCallable(List<String> out) {
            this.output = out;
        }

        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp", "execCommand/", "-Djava.security.manager", "-Djava.security.policy=execCommand/exec.policy", "-Xmx64M", "Exec");
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            process = pb.start();

            try (final Scanner scan = new Scanner(process.getInputStream())) {
                while (scan.hasNext())
                    output.add(scan.nextLine());
            }
            return process.exitValue();
        }
    }
}
```

The line `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp", "execCommand/", "-Djava.security.manager", "-Djava.security.policy=execCommand/exec.policy", "-Xmx64M", "Exec");` needs to be edited to your needs. This line executes a Exec.class file inside a folder called execCommand, which is also the location of a exec.policy file, and give it a maximum of 64MB heap.

Comment: No, I do not mean that.

Comment: And btw, can the problem be fixed if I change the command into "java -Xmx64M -Djava.security.manager HelloWorld"?

Comment: No, no problem can be fixed by that. Please read my post slowly, I believe it explains it.

Comment: Sorry about comment without reading carefully. I think I still need some time to understand your code.

Comment: I have a Github with code you might want to see: https://github.com/Xabster/Botster/. It's an IRC bot (chat) that accepts Java code with the chat, compiles it, runs it sandboxed, returns results into chat. The file that does the compiling and executing is https://github.com/Xabster/Botster/blob/master/src/commands/ExecCommand.java